# Responsive View in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

friends i am working on Android Studio to develop an app, the app will be used on Tablets and also other android phones. But i am getting some problems while designing the View (Template). Please help me to sort out this problem.

I am using ConstraintLayout as the mainLayout, and inside it i am using linearlayout with vertical orientation. You can check the code and output

If i use the listView highet as 0dp then it will show nothing

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/my_images_gallary"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

            </ListView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
[Output for the height is 0dp][1]
and if i use the ListView Height as match_parent so the bottom button will not appear.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/my_images_gallary"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Output for the height is match_parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORoid.png)
Actually i want the listView should show all with scrolling and and the button should be seen all time while the listview is being scroll or not.
[Expected Output which i am failed to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFfis.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea 1:

> give fixed height to button and textview. Then use 0dp height to listview

Idea 2:

> Use weight_sum to linear layout and give layout_weight to button,textview and listview as you expect.

Comment: After studying about weight and weight_sum, the problem solved thanks friend